# Can I "trust" request origin parameter?

Tags: ajax, http, security, cross-domain

Let's assume my site is example.com. On my server I have script which must works only for white listed site. I have setuped this code which allow XHR requests only from my site.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com')
```

Now I'm wondering can someone change origin parameter and send fake AJAX requests from another sites ?
So is origin parameter trusted or there is a ways to "override" origin parameter example from script or browser configuration or from some third part service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS policies are enforced on the client side; i.e. by the browser.

You can trust that they will work to prevent CSRF for your regular visitors, but there's nothing preventing someone from manually sending requests to you as they wish.